# Calculation Interaction Effects, Plot of Fixed Effects Model with interaction terms

Tags: r, data-visualization, interaction, fixed-effects-model, marginal-effect

I'm working with panel data using the plm package in R to estimate a fixed effects model that includes interaction terms. I'm currently able to get my model results using plm and display them with stargazer, but I'm looking for a more refined way to present these results, specifically focusing on the interaction terms. Additionally, I need to calculate and display the marginal effects of these interaction terms, including their p-values, in the same table. I'm also interested in plotting these marginal effects to better understand their impact.

Here's an example of my plm model setup:

```
fe_model_interaction <- plm(life_satisfaction ~ 
                                  employment_level_Full_Time*care_low +
                                  employment_level_Full_Time*care_high +

                                  employment_level_Part_Time*care_low +
                                  employment_level_Part_Time*care_high+
                             
                                  other_control_variables,
                                  data = data_analyse_mother, 
                                  index = c("pid", "syear"), 
                                  model = "within")
```

My questions are:

- What is the best way to display the plm model results, especially for interaction terms, in a more detailed and customizable format than what stargazer offers? I'm looking for a method to include standard errors, coefficients, and p-values in a clean and professional-looking table.
- How can I calculate and include the marginal effects of these interaction terms in the results table, along with their p-values?
- What are the recommended approaches or packages in R for plotting the marginal effects of interaction terms in a fixed effects model estimated with plm?

Comment: This is a duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77980923/display-plm-model-results-marginal-effects-p-values-for-interaction-terms-and

Comment: You might have over-specified the interaction terms in your model. It looks like `employment_level` is a categorical predictor with two levels, `Full_Time` and `Part_time`, and that `care` similarly has two levels, `high` and `low`. Is that the case? If so, it's probably best to change the formula in `plm()`. Please edit the question to say more about those predictors. Comments are easy to overlook and can be deleted.